# GraalVM generate native image failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to use the latest GraalVM(GraalVM-JDK-21-x64\graalvm-jdk-21+35.1)
to generate native image from a Spring Boot project, but it failed. Can anyone help me, thanks!
Spring boot version is spring-boot:3.1.4.
And OS is Windows 11.

I am new to GraalVM, saw that GraalVM platform can integrate some major computing languages,
so try to build a native image from a simple spring boot project.

```
 ~#@❯ mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.example:app >---------------
[INFO] Building app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.1.4:build-image (default-cli) > package @ app >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- native:0.9.27:add-reachability-metadata (add-reachability-metadata) @ app ---
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.11]: Configuration directory not found. Trying latest version.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.11]: Configuration directory is ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.4.1
...
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0]: Configuration directory not found. Trying latest version.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0]: Configuration directory is net.java.dev.jna\jna\5.8.0
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ app ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ app ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app\src\test\resources
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ app ---
[WARNING]  Parameter 'systemProperties' is deprecated: Use systemPropertyVariables instead.
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\Users\wild\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.8\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.8.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] --- asciidoctor:2.2.1:process-asciidoc (generate-docs) @ app ---
[INFO] sourceDirectory F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app\src\docs\asciidoc does not exist
[INFO] sourceDirectory F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app\src\asciidoc does not exist
[INFO] sourceDirectory F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app\src\main\asciidoc does not exist     
[INFO] No sourceDirectory found. Skipping processing
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.1.4:process-aot (process-aot) @ app ---
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)

2023-10-09T16:17:33.197+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] com.example.lpm.LightApplication    : Starting LightApplication using Java 21 with PID 34512 (F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app\target\classes started by wild in F:\MyCode\VCS-Repos\gitserver\Light\app)
2023-10-09T16:17:33.197+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] com.example.lpm.LightApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-09T16:17:34.016+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-09T16:17:34.016+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-09T16:17:34.037+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-10-09T16:17:34.058+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-10-09T16:17:34.058+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-09T16:17:34.065+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-09T16:17:34.232+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2023-10-09T16:17:34.240+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2023-10-09T16:17:35.168+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : Reflections took 234 ms to scan 50 urls, producing 484 keys and 2651 values
2023-10-09T16:17:35.210+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : Reflections took 0 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 4 keys and 5 values
2023-10-09T16:17:35.973+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : Reflections took 166 ms to scan 50 urls, producing 484 keys and 2651 values
2023-10-09T16:17:36.138+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] org.reflections.Reflections              : Reflections took 16 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 4 keys and 5 values
2023-10-09T16:17:36.206+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class com.example.lpm.controller.MailController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class com.example.lpm.controller.MailController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.216+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class com.example.lpm.controller.RootController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class com.example.lpm.controller.RootController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.310+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.466+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.487+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.498+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.513+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.529+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.544+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.544+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] rocessor$ProxyRegisteringAotContribution : Created proxy type class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController$$SpringCGLIB$$0 for class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController
2023-10-09T16:17:36.560+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] o.springframework.hateoas.aot.AotUtils   : Registering Spring HATEOAS types in org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal for reflection.
2023-10-09T16:17:36.591+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] o.springframework.hateoas.aot.AotUtils   : Registering Spring HATEOAS types in org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.forms for reflection.
2023-10-09T16:17:36.623+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] o.springframework.hateoas.aot.AotUtils   : Registering Spring HATEOAS types in org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.alps for reflection.
2023-10-09T16:17:36.623+08:00  INFO 34512 --- [           main] o.springframework.hateoas.aot.AotUtils   : Registering Spring HATEOAS types in org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.problem for reflection.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to generate code for 'org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser@2eb6d34a' with type org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateValue(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.addPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.generateSetBeanDefinitionPropertiesCode(DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.java:167)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.java:86) 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.lambda$generateBeanDefinitionMethod$3(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:192)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod$2(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:93)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$applyTo$1(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.applyTo(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Code generation does not support org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:134)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertyValueCodeGenerator.java:99)
        ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.743 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-09T16:17:36+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.4:process-aot (process-aot) on project app: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Can you run the build again with debug logging enabled (-X switch) and update your question with the output?
mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image -X